# Could not retrieve data from URL on Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a problem with my website, I post on my Facebook pages, and suddenly there is problem.

When I post my website on Facebook, it is not working, it show error "Could not retrieve data from URL", when I go to Facebook debugger I got this massage "We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know"

I read a lot on Google about this problem, but I am not Java maestro, and I don't know how to find solution for this. Please help me.

My website is www.kutakzazene.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting linke questions are off-topic in Web Applications SE.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the content of your website is fall under [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/).

Facebook is now strict and they do not retrieve content of any link which doesn't follow their community standard or try to post spam. Read them carefully.

If you think everything is fine and this is a mistake, please let them know by clicking on *please let us know* link on the debugger message as they have asked.